# How to translate "o.B." to English from German in relation to dismissal state from hospital

Tags: german-to-english, abbreviation

I have the following block of text from my discharge notes from an Austrian hospital:

> **Entlassungszustand**
>
> Blande OP-Wunde, liegende Hautklammern, periphere Durchblutung, Sensibilität, Motorik o.B., Patient mit Stützkrücken entlasten mobil.

Which I have translated to English as follows:

> **Dismissal State**
>
> Mild presentation of the surgical wound, skin stables, peripheral circulation, sensitivity, motor skills [o.B.], patient with crutches enabling mobility.

I would like to understand possible translations of the abbreviation "o.B." in Standard German possibly specific to Austrian German or medical lexigraphy.

I have used numerous online dictionaries to find an idiomatic translation however it has stumped both me and my medical translator who translated it as "Whether" which doesn't seem to scan.

Comment: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/o__B_

Comment: So... "motor skills without results" - I'm not sure I understand that.  On the basis that I cannot use my knee at the moment, could that mean "Absent of motor skills" in the joint, or some motor skills.

Comment: Actually I think this probably explains it: https://flexikon.doccheck.com/de/Ohne_Befund

Comment: FWIW: https://flexikon.doccheck.com/de/Ohne_Befund . You can find all the other terms there too (but in plain German, not in English).

Comment: One could perhaps also translate it with: "no pathology", or "no pathological results".

Answer (score 6):

o.B. is a medical abbreviation for "ohne Befund" which translates to "without (medical) findings" so

> Motorik o.B

translates to `motorically without findings`

Answer (score 3):

"ohne Befund" means: no abnormality was found for your ability to move the body part in question (from a medical and the doctors (limited) point of view). it means: no indication

Answer (score 3):

*o.B.* ist zwar kurz für "ohne Befund", bedeutet aber hierzulande "ohne **krankhaften** Befund", weil man ja immer irgendeinen Befund hat.

Im Englischen wird das allerdings etwas anders gehandhabt. Da schreibt man oft einfach *"negative"* (wobei die Kategorien oder die Fragen dann dementsprechend angepasst sind), wenn man nichts Krankhaftes gefunden hat.

Ich würde also schreiben: *"motor skill issues: negative"*.

Das in anderen Antworten benutzte *"no findings"* klingt falsch, und wäre auch nicht richtig: wie gesagt, man hat immer einen Befund, nur nicht immer einen krankhaften.

---

**Update:**

Ohne die Fragen oder Kategorien zu ändern, könnte man auch schreiben: *"no pathology"* oder *"no pathological results"*.

Answer (score 2):

I would just like to say, be careful: Use [medical dictionaries](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=medizinisches%20w%C3%B6rterbuch&atb=v146-7__&ia=web), not just regular ones, and look for *medical* definitions, because often, seemingly-innocuous words have special technical meanings for physicians.  Example: "bland" would seem to mean something like "uninteresting" but [this definition tagged *medical*](https://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/bland.html) says it means, specifically, "without inflammation".

["Motorik"](https://flexikon.doccheck.com/de/Motorik) is motor control or mobility, ["ohne Befund"](https://flexikon.doccheck.com/de/Ohne_Befund) means without further findings, i.e., nominal or normal.  (I see you found that one already, great!)

"Entlastend" you left out, it means unloaded (i.e., when using the crutches to take the load off of the knee).

Gute besserung! (Have a good recovery!)

Comment: Thanks, completely agree with the use of a medical dictionary it has been invaluable.  I have added quite a few comments to define ‘blande’ = ‘mild wound conditions without inflammation ‘.